# How do I find the minimum of a quartic function with a missing coefficient?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$ f(x) = 7x^4 + kx^3 + 8 $$
I have a question asking me to state the range of this function. To do this it seems I have to find the relationship between k and the minimum of the function. I've been told that there is a way to do this with calculus, but this is an algebra class and I haven't learned any calculus yet. I've tried coming up with random factors and then using the remainder theorem to solve for k, but that just gives me an identity.

How do I find the range of this function without knowing k?
Alternatively, is it possible to find k using the given information?

Comment: You can't.  If $k$ is large in absolute value it can make the minimum very negative.  You know the function goes off to $+\infty$ as $x$ gets large in either direction, but you can't say what the minimum is.

Comment: You can ignore the constant term (add that to the range later) and work with $7x^4 + kx^3 = x^3(7x + k),$ but I'm not sure off-hand where you can now go with this (unless $k=0).$

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(x) = 7x^4 + kx^3 + 8 $$ has a stationary point $(\alpha,f(\alpha))$ whenever for some real $v,$ $$ g(x) = 7x^4 + kx^3 + 8 + v $$ has a repeated zero $\alpha,$ i.e., $$g(x)=7(x-\alpha)^2(x^2+\beta x+\gamma)\\=7x^4+(7\beta-14\alpha)x^3+(7\alpha-14\alpha\beta+7\alpha^2)x^2+(-14\alpha\gamma+7\alpha^2\beta)x+7\alpha^2\gamma.\\$$

Comparing coefficients gives $$\alpha=0$$ or $$\gamma=\frac12\alpha\beta\\\beta=\frac23\alpha\\k=7(\frac23\alpha)-14\alpha\\\alpha=-\frac{3}{28}k.\\$$

Now, $f(x)=x^3(7x+k)+8,\ $ so $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty.$

Therefore,

- if $k=0,$ $f(x)$ has one stationary point, the minimum point $(0,8),$ so $$f(x)\in[8,\infty);$$
- otherwise, $f(x)$ has two stationary points, the inflection point $(0,8)$ and the minimum point $(-\frac{3}{28}k,8-\frac{27}{87808}k^4),$ so $$f(x)\in[8-\frac{27}{87808}k^4,\infty).$$

Comment: Since for large values of $|x|$ the term $7x^4$ is dominant, and the sum of the remaining terms is bounded (bounded from below is all we need) for other values of $|x|,$ it follows that the values of $f(x)$ cannot have arbitrarily large negative values (contrary to what you appear to be saying at the end), and so the range (because of the intermediate value property of polynomials) must have the form $[m,\,\infty)$ for some number $m$ that depends on $k.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the correction! I absent-mindedly forgot about inflection points while sketching the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Using calculus min is at $x=\frac{-3k}{28}$

How to get this without calculus is a question.

Comment: @RossMillikan  You are right.  I corrected my answer.